How to customize the way converting a C++ type to pybind::bytes?
I have a C++ class named res_data, it's an abstract type and whose pointer type (res_data_ptr = std::shared_ptr<res_data>) always works as a return type of some C++-defined functions.
Now I want these functions can be called in python throw pybind11, and hope res_data_ptr could be converted to bytes automatically in python.
Here's what I did:
// C++11
namespace py = pybind11;
struct res_data_ptr_caster
{
public:
    PYBIND11_TYPE_CASTER(res_data_ptr, py::detail::const_name("res_data"));
    static py::handle cast(const res::data& src, py::return_value_policy, py::handle)
    {
        return py::bytes();  // I didn't implement this function, but I think it doesn't matter.
    }
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(my_module, m)
{
    m.doc() = "xxx";

    m.def("my_func", load_sync);  // definition: res_data_ptr load_sync()
}

Oops! An error occurred when I was trying to import my_module and it said:
"Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was res_data"
I wonder why this happened. I defined the caster of res_data_ptr but it was still trying to find the caster of res_data. How to solve it? thanks.
I've asked ChatGPT but I'm afraid it can't help me, I tried but it can't give me any useful advice for keeping persuading me do something like export type res_data to Python but it can't work -- res_data is an abstract type and there're issues when export it to Python.
